# Phaser.Graphics / PIXI.Graphics mask

Tags: phaser-framework, pixi.js

i want a sprite with generated texture from hexGraphics(Phaser.Graphics), which is masked by hexMask object

```
var hexGraphics = new Phaser.Graphics()
    .beginFill(0x898989)
    .drawRect(0,0,80,80);

var hexMask = new Phaser.Graphics()
    .beginFill(0x0)
    .drawCircle(0,0,50)
    ;   
game.add.sprite(10,10,hexGraphics.generateTexture()); //working
game.add.sprite(110,10,hexMask.generateTexture()); //working

hexGraphics.mask = hexMask; //  http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/Graphics.html mask property

game.add.sprite(110,110,hexGraphics.generateTexture()); // no wai =(
```

here's the fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/vnbvL50h/1/`

any ideas how to generate masked texture or fix this example?

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the fiddle and the masking now works, I'm not sure if that is the result you were looking for, but essentially you can't use a graphics object to mask another graphics object, you have to use a Sprite.

```
    // create a sprite, keep a reference of it and mask it
    var hexSprite = game.add.sprite(0,0,hexGraphics.generateTexture()); 

    hexSprite.mask = hexMask;
```

Here is the official pixi example about masking : 
http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/14/